# XNA - Set The Windows is Always-on-Bottom

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, xna-4.0, always-on-top

Lets say i have created a small game with XNA. Now i can change the windows attributes of the Game by simply obtaining its Form Object by casting & do stuff with it as i can do with normal C# form.

```
Form MyGameForm = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
MyGameForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
```

now i want that this window(Form) should Always-on-Bottom, complete opposite of Always-on-Top. Meaning the window should stay on the back and never take focus even if i interact with it.

i don't know how to do it but for other stuff in C# we override that function and process whatever we want and return false. For input n text boxes etc. but i don't know how to over ride form focus method or what sets form to on top or bottom or at any index in opened windows on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need for it now, i have got the solution, i will simple avoid animating all the stuff for my self and use something that they already built, Windows Dreamscene.

Comment: but it still it would have been cool if this question would have been anwswered, i would have had the universe under my mouse pointer